# How do I ask my JSF implementation to redirect to new view through flash?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am using a flash module for site navigation (Freemind flash browser). However, I'm having trouble with navigation/redirection. A typical use case is as follows. From the welcome page, a user clicks on a country. Following that, the flash mind map appears. A user browses the mindmap, and clicks on a desired node. Embedded on this node, is a link to another page (for example, ./resources/pages/id/AirFreight.xhtml). I can get this page to load,  but I can't wire this page to a managed bean. I suppose this is because the JSF implementation is not redirected to this new view. Can anyone guide me here? How do I ask my JSF implementation to redirect to the new view through flash?  I'm a newbie using JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one is calling a page that JSF servlet is defined on its URL, if in the page there is a call to the bean - it will be invoked.

Make sure that you have JSF servlet on this URL mapping:

> ```
> <servlet>
>       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
>       <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
>   </servlet>
>   <servlet-mapping>
>       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
>       <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
>   </servlet-mapping>
> ```

What result to you see? Did you debug the code to see that it reaches any bean method? Can you post AirFreight.xhtml code and AirFreightBean.java code?

As well, considering BalusC comment, you have to run the link as `AirFreight.jsf`

Comment: In a nutshell, you need to make the link to point to `AirFreight.jsf` in order to invoke the `FacesServlet`.